# Running into "Can't Resolve" Error After Migrating from Beta 31 to RC 1 in Angular-CLI App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

In migrating from beta 31 to rc.1 in my Angular-CLI app, I am now getting some compilation errors, as it pertains to some of my custom icons/images. This is the error I'm getting:

> ERROR in ./src/app/ui/nav-menu.component.css Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve './app/img/home-icon.svg' in
>   '/Users/mk/Documents/abc/src/app/ui'  @
>   ./src/app/ui/nav-menu.component.css 6:3777-3813  @
>   ./src/app/ui/nav-menu.component.ts  @ ./src/app/app.module.ts  @
>   ./src/main.ts  @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200
>   ./src/main.ts

Specifically, what does it indicate when the error states "can't resolve"? Does that imply the item isn't where the app is looking for it? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using angular-cli put static files such as `images`, `fonts` etc.. in assets folder and refer them in you HTML files as follows

```
<img src="assets/sample.jpg" alt="some alt">
```

Comment: ERROR in ./src/app/views/login/login.component.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/assets/login-bg1.png' in

Comment: the same error ? maybe you forgot to change any other paths ? please recheck or provide error sample if it is not the same, make sure that you have paths written correctly

Comment: @Muirik you should do refactor everywhere in your code ,

Comment: I provided the error above. It's still throwing an error, even after I moved my images into the assets folder. And in my css I calling the image like this:
background-image: url('app/assets/login-bg1.png');

Comment: @Muirik please remove `app` from the url

Comment: Okay, will try that. Thanks.

Comment: That did it! Thanks much @Ashot!